# Errors after trying to compile Amazon AWS C++ SDK

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build [Amazon's C++ AWS SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-cpp) with g++ under 64 bit cygwin running on windows 8. When I call `cmake` from the build directory like so:

```
cmake C:\Users\path\aws-sdk-cpp-master
```

I get the following error:

```
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library aws-cpp-sdk-core without any source                  files. 
This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file

You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library testing-resources without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.
txt file
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library aws-cpp-sdk-dynamodb without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLis
ts.txt file

You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your
CMakeLists.txt file

You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library aws-cpp-sdk-identity-management without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with yo
ur CMakeLists.txt file

I get those errors for all folders in the directory but I cut them out.


CMake Error at C:/Users/path/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/CMakeLists.txt:59 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at C:/Users/path/aws-sdk-cpp-master/aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/CMakeLists.txt:60 (target_link_librarie
s):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "runCoreUnitTests" which is not
  built by this project.
```

I'm not really familiar with `cmake` and would appreciate any help solving this.

Comment: As for error in `add_executable`, it shouldn't occure within current project state: at least one source file, `aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/RunTests.cpp` exists. Check that you clone project correctly, and check that clone path doesn't contain symbols like space (' ').

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I'd love to help you work out any issues you are having. Did you reclone the project as Tsyvarev suggested?